# Can i upload an Android app name with punctuation to the google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it allow an application name with punctuation?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, did you get an error? If you did, what was it? (If you have not yet tried it, then go try it first)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most punctuation characters are accepted by the Google Play store (ie. colon, semi-colon, hash, brackets, question marks) as part of an app name.

If you have a specific punctuation character you wish to test then login to the [developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/), select 'Add new application' and enter your app name.